# Python 3 "virtualenv not recognized"

Tags: python, virtualenv, alexa-skills-kit

I used `pip` to install `virtualenv` to my project directory. However, when I go to run the command `virtualenv venv` in the Windows terminal, it just tells me it is not recognized.

Is there something I have to do in Python to get it to run? My understanding was it just ran like the pip script, and as long as I was in the correct directory it should run.

This is the blog post I am trying to follow: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/8e8ad73a-99e9-4c0f-a7b3-60f92287b0bf/new-alexa-tutorial-deploy-flask-ask-skills-to-aws-lambda-with-zappa

Answer (score 2):

First, install virtualenv with pip by using  `pip install virtualenv`.

After installing you can create virtualenv by `virtualenv venv`

if `virtualenv` command is not recognised by your computer that means your path is not setup properly for Python packages.
Make sure that your Python packages path is in the environmental variables.

**Or**

you can try directly `python -m virtualenv venv`